# newbie Nhibernate join query in a DetachedCriteria

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

I have a domain like this:

```
class Project
{
...
Unit ProjectUnit
}

class Unit
{
...
IList<User> Users
}

class User
{
...
```

}

I have to get all projects based on one user, so: each Project where Unit.Users contain query user.

How can I translate this to a DetachedCriteria?

Comment: when you say "contain query user", do you mean that you are using Linq to NHibernate and expect to use IQueryable? If not, does that query change?

Comment: i don't use Linq to NH. I mean that query user is the User object to use in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes you have an Id property on your User class and you're passing in a User user.

```
DetachedCriteria query = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(Project),"Project")
                            .CreateCriteria("ProjectUnit","Unit")
                            .CreateCriteria("Users","users")
                            .Add(Expression.Eq("Id", user.Id));
```